# A book on Banach space valued random variable.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

I have recently become interested in probability theory that take place on a Banach space setting. What are some good books for a beginner like me?

The topic that I am especially interested in is Banach space valued $L^p(\Omega;X)$, i.e. the space of all measurable functions $f:\Omega\to X$, where $\Omega$ is a probability space and $X$ a Banach space, such that $\int||f(\omega)||_X^p\ \text{d}\omega < \infty$.

Comment: Jusyt saw your question and I'm looking for a source that deals with covariiance of a Banach space valued random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest [Martingales in Banach spaces](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/abstract-analysis/martingales-banach-spaces?format=HB&isbn=9781107137240) by Gilles Pisier. A very preliminary version of the book (242 pages vs 580 in final version) is [available on the author's website](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~gilles.pisier/ihp-pisier.pdf).

The book begins with an introduction to Banach-space-valued $L^p$ spaces (i.e., Lebesgue-Bochner spaces). It's not long but clearly written and hits important points like the structure of the dual of $L^p(\Omega;X)$ with and without the Radon-Nikodým property.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in the stochastic equations, stochastic processes and random variables in the Hilbert and Banach spaces,I'll add a one more book:

Stochastic equations in infinite dimensions - Da Prato, Zabczyk, 1992 [[DPZ]](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/stochastic-equations-in-infinite-dimensions/6218FF6506BE364F82E3CF534FAC2FC5)

It helped me a lot when I was learning for the first time about Banach space-valued random variables.